# InvalidCastException Dictionary<string, string> using Exception.Data

Tags: c#, dictionary, exception, .net

I have a Client/Server package that I am playing with, I am trying to use Exception.Data to pass custom information into a separate class (ExceptionError) to pass into a MessageBox.

The following catch processes when I try to connect to the server without actually starting up the server to listen for connections.  just an oversight on that part, listening for connections is not the actual problem but it shows me the problem with Exception.Data.

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.Data["SourceFile"] = "Client.cs";
    e.Data["MethodName"] = "Send_CommandToServer";
    e.Data["ExceptionType"] = "Exception";
    object[] exceptionArgs = new object[8] { null, e.InnerException, 
                              e.Message, null, e.Source, e.StackTrace, 
                              e.TargetSite, e.Data };
    ExceptionError.Show(exceptionArgs);
}
```

Here is the line in the ExceptionError Class that is throwing the InvalidCastException:

```
Dictionary<string,string> data = (Dictionary<string, string>)exceptionArgs[7];
 // exceptionArgs[7] is Exception.Data
```

Here is the actual Error I am receiving:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]'.

I cannot find anything about ListDictionaryInternal, most of the google searches I have done point to System.Collections.Specialized.ListDictionary which produces issues of its own.  Does anyone know anything about ListDictionaryInternal or can you help me with passing e.Data into my ExceptionError Class?

Comment: The Exception message was quite clear, the unclear part was that I could not find anything on ListDictionaryInternal through google, and I have never used IDictionary or Exception.Data before so I was simply asking for insight from the Stackoverflow community.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Basically, the value of `Exception.Data` isn't a `Dictionary<string, string>` - so when you *cast* it to `Dictionary<string, string>`, you get this exception.

The [property itself](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.data.aspx) is only declared to be of type `IDictionary`. You shouldn't assume it's a `Dictionary<string, string>`. You should fix your `ExceptionError` class to avoid that assumption. It's documented that the keys are *typically* strings, but that's not guaranteed - likewise it's not guaranteed the the values are strings.

You can perform a "safe" conversion from `IDictionary` to `Dictionary<string, string>` by converting only the appropriate entries:

```
var dictionary = original.Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
                         .Where(de => de.Key is string && de.Value is string)
                         .ToDictionary(de => (string) de.Key,
                                       de => (string) de.Value);
```

Answer (score 2):

[Exception.Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.data.aspx) is typed (and documented) as `IDictionary`. Also, do not stuff it into an `object[]`. Instead, preserve the type information and send it as a formal parameter to `ExceptionError.Show`.

Comment: Is there a reason why someone should not "stuff" it into an object[]?  In this case it really doesn't matter to me I can change it, just wondering is there some performance penalty or something?

Comment: The reason is code clarity and maintainability. The expression `(Dictionary<string, string>)exceptionArgs[7]` is not self-explanatory. It feels like a hack that is not necessary here, because we can just add another parameter. I don't see a downside.